# check file exists java

Tags: java, file

I want create text file but if the file already exists it should not create new file but should append the text to the content (at the end) of the existing file. How can I do it in Java?

for every one second I'm reading data from inputstream when i stop reading and again i start reading data at that time i should write to same file if file already exist

does I have to check the condition:

```
if(file.exists){

} else{
   new File();
}
```

What I have to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but I guess you want to append to a file if it already exists, right?

Comment: yes, want to append to a file if it already exists

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following code to append to a file which already exists -

```
try {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename", true));
    out.write("data");
    out.close();
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

If the second argument in [FileWriter's](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) constructor is `true`, then bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

Quoting Stephen's comment:

> ...passing `true` as the 2nd
>   argument causes the file to be created
>   if it doesn't exist and to be opened
>   for appending if it does exist.

Comment: To be precise, passing `true` as the 2nd argument causes the file to be created if it doesn't exist and to be opened for appending if it does exist.

Comment: This is the best way to approach this problem.  All other check-then-create methods can fail due to non-atomic file operations.  On most systems, the append-create operation is atomic.  The FileOutputStream class directly sets up a FileDescriptor in append mode, which is the correct operation.

Answer (score 10):

> do i have to check the condition
>   `if(file.exists){ }else{ new File(); }`

No you don't have to do that: see other answers for the solution.

Actually, it would be a **bad idea** to do something like that, as it creates a potential race condition that might make your application *occasionally* die ... or clobber a file!

Suppose that the operating system preempted your application immediately after the `file.exists()` call returns `false`, and gave control to some other application.  Then suppose that the other application created the file.  Now when your application is resumed by the operating system it will not realise that the file has been created, and try to create it itself.  Depending on the circumstance, this might clobber the existing file, or it might cause this application to throw an IOException due to a file locking conflict.

Incidentally, `new File()` does not actually cause any file system objects to be created.  That only happens when you 'open' the file; e.g. by calling `new FileOutputStream(file);`

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to append to the file if it already exists there's no need to check for its existence at all using `exists()`.  You merely need to create a `FileWriter` with the append flag set to true; e.g.

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.txt", true)));
pw.println("Hello, World");
pw.close();
```

This will create the file if it does not exist or else append to the end of it otherwise.