# How to see if resource file exists in Java?

Tags: java, file, resource-files

I am trying to output text to a resource file in Java like so:

```
File file = new File(MLM.class.getClassLoader().getResource("mazes.txt").toString());
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
..
```

but because the resource file has not been created I get a null pointer exception. How can I create a blank resource file first if it doesn't exist already to avoid this error?

Comment: Please check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows

Comment: As you cannot know where the resource resides, it is not possible to always write into one. EG: You pack up your app into a JAR, and your resource gets inside the JAR archive...

Answer (score 60):

A simple null check would suffice

```
URL u = MLM.class.getResource("/mazes.txt");
if (u != null) {
         ...
}
```

From the javadoc for [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))

> **Returns:**
>       A URL object or null if no resource with this name is found

Comment: Didn't work for me, but MLM.class.getResource("mazes.txt") worked.

Comment: I need an absolute path, like this `MLM.class.getResource("/mazes.txt")`

Comment: Worked for me : URL resource = MyClassWithMainMethod.class.getResource("/myfile.xml");

Answer (score 0):

You can use before your code :

[File.createNewFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29)

> Atomically creates a new, empty file named by this abstract pathname
>   if and only if a file with this name does not yet exist. The check for
>   the existence of the file and the creation of the file if it does not
>   exist are a single operation that is atomic with respect to all other
>   filesystem activities that might affect the file.