# CSV File name check

Tags: java, file, csv, io, formatter

So I have a program where I need to create a file and read from it once.

The only issue i'm having is for how to check if the file name already exists. Right now it's only a simple set up but I'm going to have to build up on it for later high end methods and checking.

So this is what I have so far -

```
    x = new Formatter(filename + ".csv");
    x.format("%s, %s", height, weight);
    x.close();
```

So how do I let my formatter check for the already existing value "filename"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I check if a file exists? (Java on Windows)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows)

Comment: I'm using Formatter, loads of people do use File, but I prefer this.

Comment: The `Formatter` doesn't do what you are trying, probably because that code is already tested and proven valid using the `File.exists()` method as people have pointed out. Just use `File.exists()` on the path and then you can use your `Formatter`. Also, please see all of the warnings about `File.exists()` including returning true for directories and the fact that between `File.exists()` and you writing to the file someone else could have created a file so you still need to catch the `FNF`.

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(PATH, fileName + ".csv");
if (file.exists()) ...;
```