# Java File.exists() versus File.isFile()

Tags: java, java-io, java.nio.file

I'm unable to think of a realistic use case for the method [`java.io.File.exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists()) or its equivalent in Java 7 [`java.nio.file.Files.exists(Path)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)). It seems that `isFile()` or `isDirectory()` would be preferable in all cases (or `canRead()`, `canWrite()`, etc.).

For example, in [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows), the accepted answer seems silly, as the second answer points out.

Can anyone give an example where it's useful to know that a thing exists, *without* knowing whether the thing is a file or directory?

EDIT: I understand what `File.exists()` does. My question is, **when** would that functionality ever help someone? I'm searching for an example like, "Use `File.exists()` when _ _ _ _ _ _, because neither `File.isFile()` nor `File.isDirectory()` add any value in that case."

---

In retrospect, I think my confusion here was regarding two seemingly contradictory statements in the JavaDoc of the `File` class. The first sentence defines the class as,

> An abstract representation of file and directory pathnames.

That sounds like a clear dichotomy; but further in, the doc counters it with,

> Instances of this class may or may not denote an actual file-system object such as a file or a directory.

I think an example of a third file-system object would have helped immensely in the documentation; but that category seems to lack even a name, resulting in the awkward phrasing of the JavaDoc for the `Files` class: a collection of static methods,

> that operate on files, directories, or other types of files.

In the accepted answer, @koral refers to these other types as "special files". That seems apt to me. They are so special, I didn't know they existed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answering to the last question of @jaco0646:

Use `File.exists()` **when dealing with special files** like named pipes, sockets or device files.

Those are not regular files nor directories nor symlinks so both `File.isFile()` and `File.isDirectory()` will return `false` while `File.exists()` will return `true`. For example `/dev/null` (on Unix compatible OSes) is a device file.

Theoretically there **may be** performance differences visible when processing large amounts of files. This depends also on filesystem, JVM implementation details, OS etc.

Eg. on Android [`File.exists()`](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.1_r43/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java#361) is implemented using [`access()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access) system call while [`File.isFile()`/`File.isDirectory()`](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.1_r43/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/java/java/io/File.java#361) use [`stat()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). In this case processing [`stat()`](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.0_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/native/libcore_io_Posix.cpp#doStat) output requires more logic in userspace than [`access()`](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.0_r1/xref/libcore/luni/src/main/native/libcore_io_Posix.cpp#635).

Comment: Curiously, the only method which mentions devices or pipes in its documentation is [`length`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length--).

Answer (score 2):

Well it's a convenience to be able to set LinkOptions in the parameters. The actual API for this call is

```
static java.nio.file.Files.exists(Path path, LinkOption... options)
```

You might not want to follow symbolic links in the file path you specified. In this case, call Files.exists(path) - with link option `NOFOLLOW_LINKS`, and you're set.

It's also nice to have *static* methods when you don't really want to create more objects (like transient File objects) in your space than you need.

Answer (score 1):

The only use case I can think of would be one for lock files, or something similar.  A time where whether the file is a regular file or a directory is immaterial and the mere existence of something with that name is good enough to trigger program behavior.

Possibly also checking whether a cache exists.  The cache could be implemented by different providers, some of which use a directory structure and some of which use a zip file (I'm making this up as I go, by the way -- I'm not saying this is a *good* idea).