# Do I still need to check for File.exists if I already check for File.isFile

Tags: java

Currently, to check for a file whether exists, I use

```
if (file.isFile())
```

It works so far.

I was wondering, is there any edge case, which I should check the file existence by using

```
if (file.isFile() && file.exists())
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523247/java-file-exists-versus-file-isfile

Comment: this post should give the good idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20523247/java-file-exists-versus-file-isfile

Comment: You usually don't need either of them, e.g. If you're about  to open a file.