# How to solve my try-catch exception handling?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm having problems with my `try-catch exception` here. Actually what it does is to prompt the user for the name of a text file say, Robot.txt but if say the file does not exist, I have to make sure that the application reprompts the user for the file name. Hope you guys can understand I'm still a newbie here so please feel free to provide suggestions or advices on my coding etc. Cheers!

Main method class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class TestVector3 {

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the text file to read: ");
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    Vector <KillerRobot> robotDetails = new Vector <KillerRobot>();
    KillerRobot robot;

    Scanner fileInput = null;
    try
    {
        File textFile = new File(userInput.nextLine());
        fileInput = new Scanner(textFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error - file not found!");
        System.out.println("Re-enter file name :");             //Reprompt user for name of the text file
        fileInput = new Scanner(userInput.nextLine());
    }

    while(fileInput.hasNext())
    {
        robot = new KillerRobot();

        String first = fileInput.next();
        robot.setName(first);

        String second = fileInput.next();
        robot.setMainWeapon(second);

        int third = fileInput.nextInt();
        robot.setNumberOfKills(third);

        robotDetails.add(robot);
    }

    for(KillerRobot i : robotDetails)
    {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    fileInput.close();
}
}
```

KillerRobot class file:

```
class KillerRobot {

private String name;
private String mainWeapon;
private int numberOfKills;

KillerRobot()
{
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getMainWeapon()
{
    return mainWeapon;
}

public int getNumberOfKills()
{
    return numberOfKills;
}

public String toString()
{
    return name + " used a " + mainWeapon + " to destroy " + numberOfKills + " enemies ";
}

public void setName(String a)
{
    name = a;
}

public void setMainWeapon(String b)
{
    mainWeapon = b;
}

public void setNumberOfKills(int c)
{
    numberOfKills = c;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows

Comment: @m4rtin no it is not related to this question

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Maybe, the problem isn't clearly stated so I possibly made wrong assumptions.

Comment: @m4rtin you can read the question carefully if you still in doubt you can put a comment and get clarification.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera hey hi Ruchira, thank you so much for helping me to clarify my question with Martin. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you state that you are a beginner, let us first look at the relevant part of your code, to make sure that we talk about the same thing:

```
Scanner fileInput = null;
try {
    File textFile = new File(userInput.nextLine());
    fileInput = new Scanner(textFile);
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("Error - file not found!");
    System.out.println("Re-enter file name :"); 
    fileInput = new Scanner(userInput.nextLine());
}
```

You have an input and you want to check this input for a condition and require a new input **until** this condition is fulfilled. This problem can be solved using a loop like the following:

```
Scanner fileInput = null;
do {
    System.out.println("Enter file name :"); 
    try {
      fileInput = new Scanner(new File(userInput.nextLine()));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      System.out.println("Error - file not found!");
   }
} while(fileInput == null);
```

So finally, why does this work? The `fileInput` variable is set to `null` and will remain `null` until the given file is successfully read from standard input because an exception is thrown otherwise what prevents the `fileInput` variable to be set. This procedure can be repeated endlessly.

On a side note, for performance reasons, it is normally not a good idea to implement control flow that is based on exceptions. It would be better to check for a condition if a file exists via `File::exists`. However, if you read the file after checking for its existence, it might have been deleted in the meantime which introduces a racing condition.

*Answer to your comment*: In Java (or almost any programming language), you can *inline* expressions. This means that instead of calling two methods in two different statements as in

```
Foo foo = method1();
Bar bar = method2(foo);
```

you can simply call

```
Bar bar = method2(method1());
```

This way, you save yourself some space (what becomes more and more important if your code gets longer) as you do not need the value that you saved in `foo` at any other place in your code. Similarly, you can *inline* (which is how this pattern is called) from

```
File file = new File(userInput.nextLine())
fileInput = new Scanner(file);
```

into

```
fileInput = new Scanner(new File(userInput.nextLine()));
```

as the `file` variable is only read when creating the `Scanner`.

Comment: Down voters: I assume those are revenge down votes. Otherwise, please clarify your critic.

Comment: oh hey hi thank you so much for guiding me along erm may i ask you about this line of code `fileInput = new Scanner(new File(userInput.nextLine()));` I don't quite get it though. Why would you put the words new file in the line? am i able to research on that? cheers! :D

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the try-catch in a loop like below:

```
Scanner fileInput = null;
while (fileInput==null) 
{
    try
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name.");
        File textFile = new File(userInput.nextLine());
        fileInput = new Scanner(textFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error - file not found!");
    }
}
```

Next you could think of moving the File creation part into separate method, so that the code was cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Do not fall for try-catch instead add this as your functionality. Exceptions are naturally for run time error handling not for logic building.

Check if file exists at given location.

```
File textFile = new File(userInput.nextLine());

// Check if file is present and is not a directory
if(!textFile.exists() || textFile.isDirectory()) { 

System.out.println("Error - file not found!");

//Reprompt user for name of the   text file
System.out.println("Re-enter file name :");             
fileInput = new Scanner(userInput.nextLine());

 }
```

You can put while loop instead of if loop if you want to continuously prompt user until correct path is entered.

Comment: thanks for helping anyway but i'm self learning on past school work and it states i have to use the `try-catch exception` :D

Answer (score 0):

You can call back your `main()`, like following

```
 try
    {
        File textFile = new File(userInput.nextLine());
        fileInput = new Scanner(textFile);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Error - file not found!");
        main(args); // recursively call main() method 
    }
```

Now if user first attempt wrong then your code will asked to re enter file name.

How to check isFile exist?

```
  File file = new File(filePathString); 
  if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()){
     System.out.println("file exist");
  }
```

Comment: Don't use recursion for this! This way you might end up with a `StackOverflowError` if a user enters a wrong file name too many times. A user can even crash the application on purpose when looking for vunerabilities.

Comment: @raphw how many times you think? are you really think someone want to enter wrong file name nearing to million?

Comment: Being a programmer, I would write a software to do this for me.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera oh hey I learn something new here about `main(args)` didn't know that we could actually call back our main method. :D cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This really is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) because you assumed the only way to check for a file existence is by **catching** a `FileNotFoundException` (hence asking about try-catch exception handling) whereas other means exist to help you avoid a try-catch idiom in an elegant manner.

To check if a file exists at the given path or not you can simply use the [File.exists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists--) method. Please also see the [File.isFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isFile--) method and/or the [File.isDirectory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory--) method to verify the nature of the targeted File object.

EDIT : As stated by raphw, this solution is best used in *simple* scenario since it can incur a race condition in the case of concurrent file deletion happening during the file existence check. See his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25358981/3403161) for handling more complex scenario.

Comment: OP don't wanna logic to check file exists. He want to give a message and asked user to re enter file name if first attempt wrong. Read question carefully.

Comment: Please tell me in which case the user must re-enter the file name ? :)

Comment: asked user to re enter file name if first attempt contains wrong file name. Read question carefully.

Comment: Exactly, and how do you check if the file name is wrong ?

Comment: You can use `File file = new File(filePathString);
if(fileexists() && !file.isDirectory())` to check that. And currently OP asking to how to use recursion.

Comment: Right again ! So you see, my answer isn't that bad after all ;) Although I do not believe OP is really asking for recursion, I saw your post and while an interesting solution, I believe a recursion on the main function will do more harm than good because why code a complex solution when you can solve the same problem with a little *if* condition ?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera The OP is **not** asking for how to use recursion, he is asking for how to repeat the promt for the file name. As I explained in the comment to your answer, recursion is a bad solution for solving this problem. Also, the explicit check is flawed as I explained in a comment to another answer.

Comment: @raphw +1, you are completely right though I think OP is not at the point where he should worry about racing condition with concurrent file deletion hence my answer. I think he just wanted an answer to complete a simple program but in a more complex architecture where this particular problem could arise, your answer would be better.

Comment: @m4rtin This might be correct concerning today's state of learning, however as SO being somewhat an archive for solutions to problems, one should still mention these problems for anybody that reads the answers. Learning how to program is a process where you always learn new things. It should at least be pointed out to the OP that a *simple solution* might bear problems, otherwise, this learned intermediate pattern soon evolves into a bad habit as the OP continues to write more advanced application where he relies on incomplete information he picket up from here.