# Return null when file is missing or empty

Tags: java

I'm using this code to get some HDD data from Linux:

```
public void getHDDInfo() throws IOException
    {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD Model
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/model")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))

        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD Vendor
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/vendor")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))

        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD State
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/state")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD Revision
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/rev")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD SCSI Level
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/scsi_level")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD SCSI is removable
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/removable")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> ds = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get("/sys/block"), "sd*"))
        {
            // Get HDD SCSI Level
            StreamSupport.stream(ds.spliterator(), false)
                .map(p -> p.resolve("device/size")).flatMap(wrap(Files::lines))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }
```

But sometimes not all files are available or some of them are empty. Then I get this exception:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \sys\block
```

I there a way to modify the code to return null when there is no such file or the file is empty?

Comment: You need to check the file/directory exists first.

Comment: Can you show me some example?

Comment: Check with `Files.exists()`

Answer (score 5):

This should handle the cases where files don't exist:

```
try {
  // most of your stuff
}
catch (NoSuchFileException ex) {
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other better way to do this?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Better in what respect?

Comment: can you show me some example with code which checks file without exception?

Comment: @PeterPenzov http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows