# How do I read in a String from a file that may or may not be there?

Tags: java, string, file, while-loop, printwriter

I'm writing a program that opens a file that looks like this initially:

```
3000.0
Lamps 15.3 400
Chairs 19.95 250
Desks 95.0 300
```

where the first line is the balance of a company, and the rest of the lines contain the product name, the price, and the quantity, respectively.

However, throughout the program, we make changes to the file and save what's been done at the end using the Printwriting object. One of the things we can do during the course of the program is add new items to the inventory. However, I must be able to read in a product that has multiple names, i.e. desk chairs, for instance. As my code is written now, the file only reads in the name then moves right to the price, so if I try to read in a multi-word name, it gives me a runtime error as I'm trying to read in a string with a double. Therefore, how do I read in a line that MAY OR MAY NOT have two strings in it? And, if there are two strings, how do I write it so that it stores both of them in the same String variable? Here is my code:

```
    File file = new File("inventory.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<String> productName = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Double> productQuantity = new ArrayList<Double>();
    ArrayList<Double> productPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();

    double balance = inputFile.nextDouble();

    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String product = inputFile.next();
        double price = inputFile.nextDouble();
        double quantity = inputFile.nextDouble();

        //Takes those variables and stores each of them in ArrayList objects
        productName.add(product);
        productPrice.add(price);
        productQuantity.add(quantity);
    }

    inputFile.close();
```

Comment: Did you check this? [Check for existing file with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-java-on-windows)

Comment: @Freezzo — it's the String that may or may not be there, not the File.

Comment: I don't need to check if the file exists. THat I know how to do. I need to be able to read in more than one String if there is a product name with more than one word. For instance, if there is a line that says "Desk Chairs 20.5 300" I need to be able to store the name "Desk Chairs" in one String variable but for that line only because there are 3 other lines with just one word product names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is replace the spaces with hyphens or some other character while storing it in the file. That way, you could just read it out as a single word and then just replace the character with spaces, thus avoiding having to change the code you provided.

But if you have no control over how the file is written, then you could try placing the nextDouble() function in a try block to see if you are looking at the price or the next word of the name. Note here that in case the second word of the product name is a number, this will not work as designed.

```
File file = new File("inventory.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);

ArrayList<String> productName = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Double> productQuantity = new ArrayList<Double>();
ArrayList<Double> productPrice = new ArrayList<Double>();

double balance = inputFile.nextDouble();

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String product = inputFile.next();
    try{ 
        double price = inputFile.nextDouble();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        product = product+" "+inputFile.next();
        double price = inputFile.nextDouble();
    }
    double quantity = inputFile.nextDouble();

    //Takes those variables and stores each of them in ArrayList objects
    productName.add(product);
    productPrice.add(price);
    productQuantity.add(quantity);
}

inputFile.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this is not something I'm familiar with and wouldn't feel comfortable using it on a program for this class as we haven't learned it yet.

Comment: [Exception handling](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm) is a very basic concept in programming. I understand that you haven't learnt it yet, but if it solves your problem, you should definitely consider using it and more importantly, learning more about it as they are incredibly useful.

Comment: So, I did try this and it's appearing as if it worked perfectly. Thank you so much. Though, would you be able to give me a crash course in this? What is it doing exactly? And, you're saying that if I tried to do a product name in which the second word is a number, like "Desks 8" or something, this wouldn't work?

Comment: Sure, I'd be glad to help. I've already linked you to a small Exception Handling tutorial in my previous comment. I suggest reading through it and understanding how stuff words in it a bit before reading my explanation on this code.

Let me answer your second question first : Yes, if the product name is something like "Desks 8" or "Desks 8.95" this will not work.

Comment: Basically what the code I've given does is checks if the word is a number or not starting from the second name since the first is bound to be part of the product name.

If it is not a number, the program will give an error, but since the part of the program that is malfunctioning is in the TRY block, control skips over to the CATCH block instead of terminating. Any code in the catch block will obviously run ONLY if you tried putting a string into a double. Which means that the current word was part of the name and not the price.

Comment: So I took that word, appended it to the product name and then took the next word to be the number i.e price. That's pretty much it. I intentionally did as little change to your code as possible so it'll be easy for you to understand the solution. I'd also appreciate it if you upvoted my answer so that the other people who have this problem know that it is reliable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you do not want to change the input file format, you could check if the String you're reading is numeric or not.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str)  
{  
 try  
 {  
  double d = Double.parseDouble(str);  
 }  catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
    {  
      return false;  
    }  
 return true;  
}
```

For storing both Strings in same variable, use StringBuffer in case the second String is not numeric and convert the StringBuffer later to String.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so if you want to maintain your own format, you're going to need to restructure your code so that it represents that data in a simpler way. First things first, you need an `Object`. Let's call it `Product`.

```
public class Product {
    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    public Product(String name, int quantity, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now you've got a nice representation for each block, you need a nice way to write them. Now you're effectively writing a `String` back to the `File`, so let's use the `toString()` method to work out how it should look:

```
public String toString() {
    return name + " " + quantity + " " + price;
}
```

Then, you open up a `FileWriter` in *overwrite* mode, cycle through your new `List` of `Product` types, and simply write the `toString()` value. You'll notice I've not given a specific code example here. You can work it out!

**Advantages of this Approach**

- The big one is that you have an object representation of your *entire file*. That means that during the lifetime of your application, you can update the List of objects and not need to touch the file.

**Disadvantage**

- You'll need to rewrite the entire file whenever you save. Provided you're clever about when you persist your data, you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a Scanner, use a buffered reader, read line by line, then split the result and parse depending on the count:

```
File file = new File("inventory.txt");
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
double balance = Double.parseDouble(reader.readLine());
while (true) {
  String line = reader.readLine();
  if (line == null) {
    break;
  }
  String[] parts = line.split(" ");
  int count = parts.length;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < count - 2; i++) {
    if (i > 0) {
      i.append(' ');
    }
    sb.append(parts[i]);
  }
  String productName = sb.toString();
  double price = Double.parseDouble(parts[count - 2]);
  double quantity = Double.parseDouble(parts[count - 1]);

  productName.add(product);
  productPrice.add(price);
  productQuantity.add(quantity);
}
reader.close();
```