# How to check if a file exists in java

Tags: java, if-statement, inputstream, bufferedreader

Im having a problem in checking if a file exists in Java. However the IF block seems to work , but the ELSE seems dont. see, when a file exist, it will prompt a box that says, 'File found.' which happens in my program whenever a file do exist, the problem is errors flood in my console when a file dont exist. Can somebody tell me what's the easier and shorter way of coding my problem? thanks ! here's my code

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             BufferedReader br = null;
             File f = new File(textField.getText());
             String path =  new String("C:\\Users\\theBeard\\workspace\\LeapYear\\");
            try {

                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+f));
                if (f.exists())
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField.getText()+" found" );
                    while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

                         textArea.append(sCurrentLine);
                         textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField.getText()+" not found" );
                }


            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (br != null)
                    {

                        br.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

    }


    });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java

Comment: This is 2015; don't use File anymore. Use JSR 203, and in this case, `Files.exists()`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+f));
```

1. You're appending a `File` to a `String`, which doesn't make sense. You should append a `String` to a `String`, in this case `textField.getText())` appended to `path`.
2. This line will throw an exception if the file doesn't exist as per the documentation of `FileReader`:

> **Throws:**
>   `FileNotFoundException` - if the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.

This causes your program to reach the `catch` clause and print an exception stack trace. You should only call this line when `f.exists()` returns true:

```
if (f.exists())
{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path + textField.getText()));
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at these lines of your code:

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+f));
if (f.exists())
```

You are trying to open the file *before* checking whether it exists. So if the attempt to open it fails with a `FileNotFoundException`, the test is never reached.

Answer (score 0):

```
String path = "C:\\Path\\To\File\\Directory\\";
String fileName = "NameOfFile.ext";
File f = new File(path, fileName);
if(f.exists()) {
    //<code for file existing>
} else {
    //<code for file not existing>
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, just posting code does not constitute a full answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to instantiate the BufferedReader after checking the existence of the file.

```
String path =  new String("C:\\Users\\theBeard\\workspace\\LeapYear\\");
File f = new File(path + textField.getText());
...
if (f.exists())
{
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f.getAbsolutePath()));  // or br = new BufferedReader(f);
    ...
```