# Java - How I can check if file is exist?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a file with `writeToFile()` function. 
Before I call `writeToFile()` function, I want to check if the file already exist or not.
How can I do this?

### code:

```
private void writeToFile(String data, String fileName) {
    try {

        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(this.openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND));
        outputStreamWriter.write(data);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could utilize `java.io.File` and call the `.exists()` method to check if the file exists.

Use the following code to check if a file already exists.

```
if(file.exists() && !file.isDirectory()) { 
    // continue code
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Using `java.io.File`

```
File f = new File(fileName);
if (f.exists()) { 
    // do something
}
```

This is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java).

Comment: if it's a dupe - why no close-vote?

Comment: @Jan because I thought marking as duplicate was different to closing and I couldn't see how to do the former. I've now read the manual :)

Answer (score -3):

```
 File file = new File("FileName");
if(file.exists()){
  System.out.println("file is already there");
}else{
   System.out.println("Not find file ");
}
```

The methods in the Path class are syntactic, meaning that they operate on the `Path` instance. But eventually you must access the file `system` to verify that a particular Path exists