# How do I check if no other files exist

Tags: java, file

I load some files from a folder which have names `file 1.pdf`, `file 2.pdf` etc
I want to load them all to my program. If I new the total number of them, I would do sth like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=100; i++){
   File pdfFile = new File("file "+i+".pdf");
   //...
}
```

But I don't know the total number.. What would be the condition so when there is no other file, then exit ?

```
do{
      File pdfFile = new File("file "+i+".pdf");
      //...
}while(//there are files...)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two approaches to this - you could simply keep incrementing your counter until you get a file that doesn't exist, i.e.

```
int i = 1;
File file;
while((file = new File("file "+i+".pdf")).exists()) {
    // do whatever
    ++i;
}
```

The imho less clumsy approach would be to simply iterate over all files in a particular directory and just ignore those with names not matching your pattern (that is, unless the order in which you're processing your files is important).

Comment: How does this work? Because `.exists()` returns a boolean? Edit: Ah I see how it should work, but you are missing a `)`.

Comment: @martijnn2008 `exists` returns true if the file exists, yes. This relies on the fact that assignment in Java, like in C and C++, is actually an expression with a value rather than a statement (specifically, it has the value that was assigned).

Answer (score 1):

You could catch an exception and break a while loop. Originally I had answered:

```
boolean success = true;
int i = 0;

while(success){

    i = i + 1;

    try{
        File pdfFile = new File("file " + i + ".pdf");
    } catch(FileNotFoundException ex){
        success = false;
    }
}
```

But I have been told that constructors do not throw exceptions, so this would not work. Therefore you would be best using the answer below, as another user (@cubic) suggested.

```
int i = 0;
File file;

while((file = new File("file " + i + ".pdf")).exists()){
    // something with file
    i++;
}
```

Comment: it doesn't seem like this is going to help. there is no exception thrown by the constructor when the file doesn't exist (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Comment: Ahh, I didn't know that! I will edit this.

Comment: The second part of you answer was already given by someone else, and it was wrong initially.

Comment: Edited to explain why my method wouldn't work (and accepted your edit as well as credit the proper answer).

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the dependency Apache Commons IO, your code would look like this:

```
File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\your.directory\\");
FileFilter fileFilter = new WildcardFileFilter("file *.pdf");
File[] files = dir.listFiles(fileFilter);
for(File file : files){
    System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Comment: Close, but not quite. His question has him iterating over "file <a number>.pdf", while yours would iterate over "file <anything>.pdf"

Also, it seems like he wants his numbers to be consecutive. Of course if the actual intent was to just iterate over all pdfs in the directory, this is valid.

Comment: That's true... And it seems that i can't use regex inside the Wildcard Filter...

Answer (score 0):

You should count number files into the folder

```
new File(<directory path>).listFiles().length
```

Comment: Doesn't work if there are other file (not pdf for example) in the directory