# Run shell inside watch service in java

Tags: java, shell, watchservice

I want to run shell script inside watch service class to run the shell after new file add to folder.
Watch service is working perfectly but when I want to add `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("home/user/test.sh")`; I recived error.
I just add Runtime after this:

```
   // Dequeueing events
                    Kind<?> kind = null;
                    for(WatchEvent<?> watchEvent : key.pollEvents()) {
                        // Get the type of the event
                        kind = watchEvent.kind();
                        if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                            continue; //loop
                        } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                            // A new Path was created 
                    Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                            // Output
                            System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);
                          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("home/user/test.sh")
```

What I have to do?

Comment: what version of java are you using? also that is really really wrong what you did, any reason why can't call the shell script from within code?

Comment: I am using java version 1.7. I know it is wrong. literally I don't know what should I do. But the requirement is, I have to watch one folder, when new file add, run specific script in command line

Comment: i am pretty sure java has a folder watcher API you are not using. And again is there any reason you cant put this script on the system and call from within the code?

Comment: I am using this tutorial for watching the folder http://andreinc.net/2013/12/06/java-7-nio-2-tutorial-writing-a-simple-filefolder-monitor-using-the-watch-service-api/

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/WatchDir.java this might be a better example

Comment: The only reason is I want to do everything automatically. I mean when one folder ( in my case movie) add to path, i want to run ffmpeg script to convert it from mp4 to avi. for this I have to write ffmpeg script in shell and then run it from inside the code

Comment: huh? well i don't think that is possible by what you are doing. you are basically doing command line commands and not a shell script when java does that stuff unless you call a shell script

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.exec(new String[] {"/path/to/bash", "-someArgs", "path/to/script" })` ?

Comment: so there is no way to run command line from inside the java code?

Comment: @csharpfolk oh duh i got confused with what they was saying i thought they programmed the script inside the java. but they should be using processbuilder not runtime.exec

Comment: actually I am girl;) by the way no I didnt write command line inside the code. I want run command line from the code with using bash file

Comment: @csharpfolk i have to write this after creating new folder?

Comment: @Aira ok well in that case use processbuilder which has practically replaced runtime.exec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing problems with running script have nothing to do with `WatchService`, since you don't post actual exception that is throws (that would help a lot) I can only guess what is wrong, so please check this:

1. Script doesn't have permission to execute (easily fixable by `chmod +x path/to/script.sh`) - in that case you would get `IOException` with message like `Permission denied` or similar
2. System cannot find your script, since you are using relative path (no `/` at the beginning of script name) in that case ether use full script name e.g. `/home/user/foo/script.sh` or use proper relative path `../foo/script.sh` - you should check if script exists before running it via exec ([How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java))
3. Beware that script may be called with working directory of running Java program - so you should pass newly created file path as parameter to script to make it independent of its location

I followed tutorial that you were using with code:

```
if (OVERFLOW == kind) {
                        continue; //loop
                    } else if (ENTRY_CREATE == kind) {
                        // A new Path was created
                        Path newPath = ((WatchEvent<Path>) watchEvent).context();
                        // Output
                        System.out.println("New path created: " + newPath);
                        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/home/xxx/foo.sh", newPath.toString() });
                    }
```

and script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "FILE CREATED: $1" >> /home/xxx/watch_dir.log
```

and it worked without any errors.