# Test path is accessible or not in java

Tags: java

I have a path i.e. "K:\user\abc.xml". I want to validate that path only that is valid or not, no need to create file at this location. I used file writer but it's create file. So please guide me what should I do?

Don't go with file please help me for path validation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Create a `File` object:

```
File f = new File("K:\user\abc.xml");
```

and test if it exists:

```
if (f.exists()) {}
else {}
```

Comment: But I have  an aplication which take path as in text box and pressing next button it will create file. But at some condition I don't want to create file, but user can enter anything in path like I have not 'k' drive so it should generate exception that path is not valid.

Comment: I have an application which take path as in text box and after pressing next it will create file at that location, but at some condition I have not create file . But user can enter anything in this path field so I have not 'k' drive so it should generate exception that path is not valid. I want such type of output. Please suggest me

Comment: The code does not create any file... Creating a `File` object does not creates a file.

Comment: Do u understand what I m saying?

Comment: I dont want file.exist() . I want only path validation there is no such drive in my system so why should I check that file exist or not . Simple I want path is valid or not?

Comment: Do you understand what you say? What does it means "path validation"? I know what it means if a path correspond to a file or not, but path validation is not clear. You mean syntactic validation?

Comment: Jean, valid path - D:\abc because D is your drive but not a valid path- X:\abc because X is not your drive.

Comment: Then decompose the `File` with several calls to `parent()` and test exists on them. If you want, you can call `listRoots` and search for your drive.

Comment: Provide some generic solution, what happen if you have network path, I.e //10.1. 2.4/abc/abc.xml but that network is not accessible then it should also work like system drive path.

Answer (score 0):

```
File f = new File("c:/temp"); 

    if(f.exists()){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }else{
        System.out.println("no");
    }
```

This code will validate the given directory (or Path) is exists or not. 
Here are the possible results:
if i have temp folder in c drive : yes
if i don't have temp folder in c drive : no
if you are writing to root directory like "C" path should  "C:" (you should handle if user enter only "C" just append ":"

But, it purely dependent code for windows platform, you should think through platform independent.

Happy Codding.

Comment: It's ok if drive is your system drive, but what happen if drive is x, y, z I think this is not your system drive at this this it will show same output, But x is not a drive so it is invalid path, right?

Comment: No x could be a drive, so such a path is valid... Now is the real problem not "does it reflect something existing or not?"

Comment: Put path which is not in your system like you have c drive D drive etc then you entered something else and then validate that it is valid path or not.