# Selenium -Check if Save File dialog is opened Firefox

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

My function is that when user click the button, a filed is downloaded. Normally, a dialog from native OS is there to notify you

In the Selenium test, I do not know how to check if such dialog is opened (Indication of file downloaded successfully). I do not want Selenium to download it, just looking for the sign of a successful download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Therre is no direct way from Selenium  but you can check if the downloaded file exists in the path Using java.io.File:

```
File f = new File(filePathString);
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    // do something
}
```

as per [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Comment: Added as accepted since if you enable auto download using Firefox Profile, it would work, but if they asking for Save option then this would not work.