# Android Mp3 File - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: java, android

I'm not understanding why I am getting this exception. The directory itself seems to be there. I can play the music locally, but when I try to do this: `FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(audioFile);` I get this error: `/document/2710: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`

**Here is my full Code:**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        if ((data != null) && (data.getData() != null)) {

      Uri audioFileUri = data.getData();
      File file = new File(audioFileUri.getPath());
      //file.mkdirs();  <---- Making a directory does not work
      try {
             FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(audioFile); //This is where I get the error
           }
      catch{
             Log.i("TAG", e.getMessage());  
            }

     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Check programatically if the file exists and you have correct permissions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(audioFileUri.getPath());
```

At best, that line might work if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. In your case, it is `content`.

Use `getContentResolver().openInputStream()` to open an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri`. This works for both the `file` and the `content` scheme.

Comment: Your answer in a different post actually solved my problem. I changed `FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(audioFile);` to `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` and now it works like a charm.