# JFileChooser check if really a File is selected?

Tags: java, swing, file, jfilechooser

I noticed the following: If I start my application and go to open a file, then the `JFileChooser` appears. I tried writing a filename and I did not get an error, even though the file does not exist. What I get is a file path.

```
 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    int values = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

    if (values == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
    } else if (values == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("No file is selected");
    } else if (values == JFileChooser.ERROR_OPTION) {
        System.out.println("Error!");
    } else if (file == null) {
        System.out.println("No File is chosen");
    }
```

I hope you guys can help. I hope my question is clear because I have problems with explanations and with the English language.

Answer (score 1):

you can check if a file exists with: file.exists(). Already answered in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java).
The creation of a file object does not garuantee that a file at your path does exist.

```
...
if (values == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    if(file.exists()){
        System.out.println(file.getPath());
    }else{
        System.out.println("file does not exist");
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Sorry I dont find this post. I try it out

Comment: It work but I get the statement of values==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION why?

Comment: JFileChoose just let you pick any path. If it was a succesfull selection of a path, then it is "approved". Succes for the JFileChooser does not mean that the slected file also exists. What if you want to select a non existend file, because you want to save something?