# How to increment number in new file name?

Tags: java

I am currently writing a method in Java where I am trying to create new files but I need those files not to be of the same name, but rather of incrementing name values, like so:

/Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile0.xml

/Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile1.xml

/Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile2.xml

/Users/Myself/Desktop/myFile3.xml

So I have tried to do the following in my code, but I do not understand why when I call the file within the for each loop ( to create a new one) the number does not increment?

```
public void pickFolder() throws Exception {

    chooserFolder.setDialogTitle("Specify your save location");
    chooserFolder.setDialogType(JFileChooser.SAVE_DIALOG);

    int numbers = 0;
    chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"));
    chooserFolder.setFileFilter(new FileNameExtensionFilter("xml file", "xml"));

    int userSelection = chooserFolder.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {

        for (File file : files) {

            chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File(chooserFolder.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()));

            fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();
            if (fileToSave.createNewFile()) {
                System.out.println("File is created!");
                fileToSave = chooserFolder.getSelectedFile();

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File already exists.");
            }

            System.out.println("Save as file: " + fileToSave.getAbsolutePath());

        }
```

Comment: Where you increment you loop?

Comment: You write about a for-loop that is not in the code you posted. please extend your example.

Comment: I don't understand, is all that code inside a for-loop? Then you should declare the variable numbers outside that loop.

Answer (score 2):

What I'm seeing in your code is that you set numbers to ZERO right before incrementing it. try putting `int numbers=0` out of your loop if there is any! (you have not written any loop in the code). And of course giving more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

your for-loop has no counter which can be increased, because it is a for-each-loop (if that is the loop you mean). also you call `chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers++ + ".xml"));` only once and there is the only occurrence of `numbers++`. To given an proper solution you would need to provide all the code. also this line makes no sense at all `chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File(chooserFolder.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()));`. once you give all the code we can provide a solution

Answer (score 0):

Please use the timestamp solution for this problem

```
String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmm'.txt'").format(new Date());
```

Here have a better example below

```
package com.seleniummaster.examplefile;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class CreateFileWithTimeStamp {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      CreateFileWithTimeStamp("test");
    }

    //Create a new file
    public static void CreateFileWithTimeStamp(String filename) {
        //get current project path
        String filePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        //create a new file with Time Stamp
        File file = new File(filePath + "\\" + filename+GetCurrentTimeStamp().replace(":","_").replace(".","_")+".txt");

        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                System.out.println("File is created; file name is " + file.getName());
            } else {
                System.out.println("File already exist");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        // Get current system time
    public static String GetCurrentTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");// dd/MM/yyyy
        Date now = new Date();
        String strDate = sdfDate.format(now);
        return strDate;
    }
    // Get Current Host Name
    public static String GetCurrentTestHostName() throws UnknownHostException {
        InetAddress localMachine = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String hostName = localMachine.getHostName();
        return hostName;
    }

    // Get Current User Name
    public static String GetCurrentTestUserName() {
        return System.getProperty("user.name");
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to check IF a file exists, but with a WHILE you must be able to do so:

```
while (f.isFile("myFile" + numbers + ".xml") == TRUE) {number++} // end while

chooserFolder.setSelectedFile(new File("myFile" + numbers + ".xml"));
```

Reference:
[How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)