# How to check whether a file exists in (Internal/External storage) by using file name?

Tags: java, android, file

I have been working on a project where I will get a filename from API and have to check whether the file is present in the device and play it.

I am getting `Screenshot.jpg` as filename from API and under the same name a file is present in my storage.

But when I used the piece of code, I have been returned false. I have checked with other codes also.

```
public boolean isFilePresent(String fileName) {
    String path = this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + fileName;
    File file = new File(path);
    return file.exists();
}
```

where am I going wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Comment: Try printing the path and then verify it exists (by ssh or manually opening it in a file browser).
Your check is correct, the only suspect is a wrong path

Comment: Well its not duplicate! I don't know the path to the file by any means. In the said link, pathtothefile has to be passed on

Comment: Thanks @GuyKhmel, I will check it once

Comment: hi, send us your insertion code of file

Comment: Can you log the path of the file and then the value in `path` variable and check, if they are same?

Comment: File dir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mycalender/download");
            if (dir.exists() == false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl + fileName);
            File file = new File(dir, fileName);

Comment: Extremely sorry for that @greenapps. After comparing the paths, i solved it. Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, what you do wrong is using `this.getFilesDir()`.

Instead, use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` for example, it's all dependant on where your file is.

Like I said before, debug it yourself, print (or present a toast) with the 'expected' file path, then verify it doesn't exist

Comment: Need not do `toString()`. Instead it can be done like this `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Screenshot.jpg");`

Comment: Path is the culprit ! Thanks all !

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
public boolean isFilePresent(Context context, String fileName) {
    File dirFiles = context.getFilesDir();

    File[] filesArray = dirFiles.listFiles();

    for (File file : filesArray) {
        if (file.getName().equals(fileName)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: This didn't helped me @Thomas Mary. I have been returned false again

Answer (score 0):

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` this is how you get the files directory

then you will add your files path after it, so you should do something like this

```
if(!new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/myFolder/"+"myFile").exist())
{
// file is not exist
}
```

**remember to check the runtime permission because it's a special permission**