# How to check if file exists knowing only file name?

Tags: java

In Java using Maven project we may read file's content as a stream by knowing only file's name, for example:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/" + fileName);
```

But is there way to check if the file exists without indicating the whole path, just passing file name?

Comment: File f = new File(fileName); if (f.exists()) ... that should do the trick

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check if a file exists in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816673/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-java)

Comment: A resource is not necessarily a file? And the above will return null if your resource does not exist (which is the check for a resource existing)

Comment: The problem is your terminology. You are erroneously calling a resource a "file". The Java definition of a file is something that resides in a filesystem A resource does not: it typically resides in a jar as a zip entry. By asking about files, you are getting the wrong answers.

Answer (score 0):

`file.exists()` can be used to check whether such a file exists or not.Like following:

```
File file = new File("filepath"); 
if(file.exists()){
   // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: the main point here is to avoid filepath, just knowing the name of the file

Comment: @flintEastvood without knowing where the file is, you can't check anything ... obvious. You can check that A file exists with said name. just do a recursive search over all your directories and check in each if the file is there.