# How to see if a file with the same name already exists

Tags: java, file

What I tried to do is to see if a file with the same name already exist in the folder. I have tried to use the method file.exists, but it only says if a file exists in the folder.

```
if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    file = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toString() + ".html");

    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
        if (file.exists()) {
            int ergebnis = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(TiltungsplanGUI.this,
                    "The File exists already. Overwrite?", "Meldung",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (ergebnis == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                writer.write(r.getTilgungsplan());
            }
        }

        writer.close();

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TiltungsplanGUI.this, e1.getMessage());
    } catch (RatenRechnerException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(TiltungsplanGUI.this, e1.getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you searched to *how to see if a question already exist* ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1816707/442451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new FileWriter(file)
```

creates the file. It's nonsensical to check whether it exists after you have just created it.

You may want to move the check before the creation of the `FileWriter` ...

Comment: What about race condition?

Comment: Good point. If races are possible, I'd use `Files.newBufferedWriter(path, charset, StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW)` to create the file only if it doesn't exist yet.