# How to avoid FileNotFoundException?

Tags: java, arraylist, file-io, exception

I'm wondering how to make it so that my program creates a file if it does not already find it there?

```
public void load() throws Exception {
    try
      {
        File log = new File(FILE_NAME); //opens the file
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(log);
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn); //de-serializes
        videosList = (ArrayList)in.readObject(); // de-serializes
        in.close(); //closes the file
        fileIn.close();
      } catch(Exception i)
      {
         i.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Users/hanaezz/Desktop/output.ser (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at videostore.BinaryFile.load(BinaryFile.java:31)
    at videostore.VideoStore.<init>(VideoStore.java:33)
    at videostore.VideoStore$6.run(VideoStore.java:430)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

All the extra stuff there is because my program is also a GUI program. And then I also have a method that's supposed to write my object to a file...

```
public void writeToFile() throws Exception{
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE_NAME);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        oos.writeObject(videosList);
        oos.close();
        outputStream.close();
        }
```

This throws the same exception. How can I avoid this? I'm not sure how to modify the FIS/OIS to create the file if they don't find it.. or I suppose it would be more efficient for the FOS/OOS to do it instead?

Comment: Err, don't try to open a non-existent file? In this case you appear to be missing a leading `/` in the filename.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check file exists java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237235/check-file-exists-java)

Comment: @Ducaz035 Definitely not. That one is about appending to an existing file.

Comment: You can't open an empty file with an ObjectInputStream, so creating it won't help.  You should instead handle a missing file, and you should give it the correct path.

Answer (score 1):

```
Users/...
```

You are missing a leading `/` in the filename. So you can't create it, so you can't read it.

Comment: Can you please able to elaborate your answer with more working code

Comment: @Suganthan You're kidding, right? You don't know how to add a leading `/` to a filename?

Comment: But it is not there is user code right..?

Comment: @Suganthan That's not even a sentence, let alone a question.

Comment: You are right? But does it will help the OP?

Comment: @Suganthan Please express yourself in standard English. I don't know what will help the OP any more than you do, but I do know what is wrong with his software.